# error with deviding by 0 but no zero in the code

Tags: java, fibonacci

I am trying to solve Project Eleur coding problems with java(each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89 By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.) I did this code

```
public class JavaApplication15 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a1=1;
        int a2=2;
        int a3;
        int aux;
        int sum=3;
        a3=3;
        while(a3<=4000000){
            a3=a1+a2;
            aux=a2;
            a2=a3;
            a1=aux;
            if(a3%0==0){
                sum+=a3;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("the sum is"+sum);
    }
```

I don't know if it will display the right answer BUT the error I get while compiling the code is  exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero

Comment: What is your intent with `a3%0==0`? That is division by 0. Also, please always post the full error with trace if your question is about an error.

Comment: As I know it is for the reminder

Comment: It is, but it's a similar operation to division. What is your intent with trying to get the remainder after dividing `a3` by 0?

Comment: @hamzabouabid What do you think a remainder is, other than what's left over after division?

Comment: It is a runtime exception, not a compile error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments pointed out, you get an ArithmeticException because % (modulo) returns the remainder of a division, in other words it performs a division.

That's as if you would write a3/0, same exception.

> By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms

I think you probably want to sum the even fibonacci values. For that case modulo is the correct operand, however you have to divide by 2 and check if the remainder is 0.